# Why iphone 6s frequently restarts?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, restart

I have an iphone 6s with 76% battery health.
the problem started, when it got frozen and touch screen didn’t work.so I held the power button to restart my phone.
when it got restarted, while booting, a horizontal white line appeared in my black screen then it turned on.
Now I am having a problem with it.
It randomly restarts with the same white horizontal line.
what can I do about it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Take it to Apple. It's a 5-year-old phone with hardware problems. Apple will agree to replace the battery when the health is below 80%. The charge for a battery replacement is quite small.

If there are other problems, then you may want to save your money and think about an upgrade.